# affine2d's outputLimits - what does it do?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I really tried to understand what this function does, but alas, I failed... I thought it works like this:

```
[transformedXMinMax transformedYMinMax] = outputLimits(tform,[xMin xMax],[yMin yMax]);
```

which should be equivalent to

```
[transformedXMinMax transformedYMinMax] = transformPointsForward(tform,[xMin xMax], [yMin yMax]);
```

But according to the example, it does not...
Does anyone know what it does?

Comment: Maybe you mean `outputLimits` ? :D

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam heh, you're right :p do you know what it does?

Comment: really no :( just find it in help. And what is `forwaredTransform`? I can't find it

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam heh, another misspelled function - transformPointsForward :) I found outputLimits in the help: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine2d.outputlimits.html - but I can't understand what it does...

Comment: I read the description of both of them and I find the difference: `outputLimits` just estimates output signal limits, `transformPointForward` applies your geometric transformation! And `[transformedXMinMax transformedYMinMax]` didn't returns min and max values - it returns whole array of transformed points

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam what does estimating output signal limits mean? lets say my transformation is a 30 degree rotation, and i give it [1 320] and [1 640] as my x and y inputs respectively - what's the answer you expect it to output, and why?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I got it, thanks :) the documentation could have been more elaborate if it would have talked about rotating the bounding box and returning the new corners of it.

Comment: I really don't know, but I suggest assume it would  something like x = [1 597] and y = [-160 554]. The problem - I don't know where is the rotation center. So let's try this? use this limits for your transformation and let's check it!

Comment: So, are we were right? it just calculates min max coordinates of rotated (transformed) box? And it's rotates it around (1 ,1), isn't it?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam it's rotating around (0,0). it's the same as applying transformPointsForward(tform, [1 597 1 597], [-160 554 554 -160]) and choosing the min and max from the answer.